# How to export data of array to excel with each element from an array storing in single row

Tags: excel, laravel

I am trying to export data to excel using [Fast excel](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel). This is easy for straight forward export. However, I have data as follows:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => name1
                    [multiple_units] => ["80","103","126","7","10","13"]
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => name2
                    [multiple_units] => ["30","23","26","7","25","33"]
                )

        )

)
```

Where `multiple_units` is a text column with `json_decode`. So, now when I try to export data with following code:

```
    public function exportTest()
    {

        $reviews = DB::table('test_db')->get();

        $file_name = 'Review - '.date('Y_m_d').'.xlsx';

        return (new FastExcel($reviews))->download($file_name,function($review){
            $unit_lists = '';
            if($review->multiple_units != NULL){
                $unit_ids = json_decode($review->multiple_units, true);

                foreach($unit_ids as $uk => $uv){
                    return [
                        'Name' => $review->name,
                        'Units' => $uv
                    ];
                }

            }

        });

    }
```

It export to excel file like as:

```
Name    Units
name1   80
name2   30
```

However, I want to export with each unit being in a single row. For instance,

```
Name    Units
name1   80
name1   103
name1   126
name1   7
name1   10
name1   13
...
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, Fast Excel does not allow changing the number of rows in the callback function.

The solution is to manipulate the data before passing it to Fast Excel:

```php
    public function exportTest()
    {
        $reviews = DB::table('test_db')->get()->flatMap(function ($review) {
            $items = [];

            if ($review->multiple_units != NULL) {
                $unit_ids = json_decode($review->multiple_units, true);

                foreach ($unit_ids as $uk => $uv) {
                    $items[] = [
                        'Name' => $review->name,
                        'Units' => $uv
                    ];
                }
            }

            return $items;
        });

        $file_name = 'Review - '.date('Y_m_d').'.xlsx';

        return (new FastExcel($reviews))->download($file_name);
    }
```

This will map over each review return an array containing name and units for each unit. Then the array is flattened and passed to Fast Excel.

**Note:** This will ignore any reviews where `review->multiple_units == NULL` (which includes an empty string)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function exportTest() {

        $reviews = DB::table('test_db')->orderBy('name')->get();

        $file_name = 'Review - '.date('Y_m_d').'.xlsx';

        return (new FastExcel($reviews))->download($file_name,function($reviews) {

            foreach ($reviews as $review) {
                # code...
                if(!empty($review->multiple_units)) {

                    $unit_ids = json_decode($review->multiple_units, true);

                    foreach($unit_ids as $uk => $uv){
                        return [
                            'Name' => $review->name,
                            'Units' => $uv
                        ];
                    }

                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Not working, its showing `undefined variable $reviews`. This is clear as you are not passing reviews variable inside that function. Also, is not it would double the loop if we place `foreach($reviews)`

Comment: It was a typo $review --> $reviews
fixed : ->download($file_name,function($reviews)
See updated answer

Comment: local.ERROR: Call to a member function toArray() on null